# Как пропустить Please enter your phone (or bot token): в Telethon

Tags: python, input, async-await, asyncio, telethon

У меня есть определенный набор Telegram аккаунтов в виде Telethon сессий, и какие-то из них рабочие, а какие-то нет. Если рабочие, то функция выполняет определенный скрипт и все ок, а если же он нерабочий, то Telethon выдает мне input с предложением ввести телефон или токен `Please enter your phone (or bot token):`

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы если аккаунт не рабочий, то мой код просто бы пропускал этот пользовательский ввод и выходил из функции?

Мой код:

```
import asyncio
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient


async def work(account):
    session = account['session']
    api_id = account['api_id']
    api_hash = account['api_hash']

    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy)
    res = await client.get_me()
    print(res)


async def main():
    for a in accounts:
        await work(a)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение в виде костыля, но все же

```
import telethon

try:
   client = await TelegramClient(session_path, api_id, api_hash).start('0')
   print('good session')
except telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.PhoneNumberInvalidError:
   print('fail session')
   return False
```